# Angular app in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, angular

I'm trying to load an angular app in a Lightning Web Component.
Did anyone manage to do that successfully?
I'd love to see an example.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you add relevant code snippets? is it LWC on SF or LWC opensource?